# Producer Consumer: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, semaphore, producer-consumer

I am trying to write the Operating systems producer consumer problem in C. I am getting the above mentioned "Segmentation Fault". Its hard to explain everything here, so I have posted the code on github. A look would give you a better picture of what I want to ask.

Github Link: https://github.com/Shad0walker/Producer-Consumer.git

Order of my files:
`prod_cons_s.c` (Main file)
`sem.h (includes threads.h)`
`threads.h  (includes q.h)`
`q.h (includes TCB.h)`

Here is the exact problem I am facing.

I am getting this error when I try to perform a V operation and bring a sleeping process back from SemQ to RunQ. 
Here is the scenario for producer consumer.

I have a RunQ with Producer -> Consumer -> Consumer -> Producer -> Consumer.

1. The first producer produces an item. SUCCESS
2. Consumer consumes that item. SUCCESS
3. This consumer calls `P(&EMPTY)`and bumps down the semaphore counter to -1. thereby deleting this consumer process from RunQ and adding it to SemQ. Context is swapped with CPU running the next process (Producer) in the RunQ. SUCCESS
4. Now when the next producer runs, in the end it should call `V(&EMPTY)`bumping the semaphore counter back to 0 and bringing the sleeping process in STEP 3 back to RunQ.`ERROR`

Here is where I am getting this error.
Any help would be highly appreciated !!!

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and stack traces.

Comment: Don't define functions in header files like that.

Comment: Hey guys, yeah I used GDB to debug, it was pretty helpful to find the NULL pointer I was trying to dereference. Which was throwing the error. Its working now ! Thanks again.